# How to set a time limit for a Kubernetes job?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, jobs, kubernetes-jobs

I'd like to launch a Kubernetes job and give it a fixed deadline to finish. If the pod is still running when the deadline comes, I'd like the job to automatically be killed.

Does something like this exist? (At first I thought that the Job spec's `activeDeadlineSeconds` covered this use case, but now I see that `activeDeadlineSeconds` only places a limit on when a job is re-tried; it doesn't actively kill a slow/runaway job.)

Comment: How about leveraging liveness probe? You could create a probe that returns success for the time you need and after the deadline is reached it would return failure(1) and kill container. More info about liveness probe: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Comment: I think this is actually a very good feature request. Is it somewhere tracked in the Kubernetes Github?

Answer (score 17):

From the way I understand the documentation of `activeDeadlineSeconds` section is that it refers to the active time of a Job and after this time the Job is considered `Failed`.

**Official doc statement:**

The activeDeadlineSeconds applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup

Answer (score 16):

You can self-impose timeouts on the container's entrypoint command by using GNU `timeout` utility.

For example the following Job that computes first 4000 digits of pi will time out after 10 seconds:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["/usr/bin/timeout", "10", "perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(4000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

(Manifest adopted from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job)

You can play with the numbers and see it timeout or not. Typically computing 4000 digits of pi takes ~23 seconds on my workstation, so if you set it to 5 seconds it'll probably always fail and if you set it to 120 seconds it will always work.

Comment: Thanks! I like this a lot, though it forces the pod template to know about the default command of the image, rather than just *running* the image. That's a bit unfortunate, but it's definitely a workable solution.

Comment: Just FYI you can always create variables for the arguments e.g. `$TIMEOUT`, and have its value coming from a ConfigMap mount, so you don't have to hardcode. This way you can modify it in the ConfigMap and the new jobs will use the new value.

Comment: That's a good point -- though the spec still needs to know the default command for the image.

Comment: using `timeout` cli is a pretty good way to handle it, I've totally over-engineered it (https://blog.random.io/k8s-cronjob-with-execution-timeout/)

Comment: I usually end the `command:` portion of the yaml with `bash -c` and then put the command you care about in the `args:` section. That way the `command` never changes, and it's easier to write a natural command line in `args` because it doesn't require any awkward quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead add the activeDeadlineSeconds to the pod spec in the pod template defined as part of the job. This way the pods which are spawned by the job are limited with the timeout.

Comment: timeout is of linux utility whereas activeDeadlineSeconds is correct practise in this case.

Comment: in my case adding `activeDeadlineSeconds` caused pods to be immediately removed so that there is no way to inspect logs of failed container :(

Comment: Ok. my previous comment was wrong. I've added `activeDeadlineSeconds` into job definition instead of pod. In order to keep pod, you need to set `activeDeadlineSeconds` on pod. But in this case you will restrict time for a single pod run. By default job has `backoffLimit: 6` which means that job can take `7 * activeDeadlineSeconds`